# Laravel Confide not triggering eloquent.saving

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [`zizaco/confide`](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) in combination with [`cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable`](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable).

eloquent-sluggable uses `Events::listen('eloquent.saving*')` for generating the slug while/before saving.

```
// Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider:55

public function registerEvents()
{
    $app = $this->app;

    $app['events']->listen('eloquent.saving*', function($model) use ($app)
    {
        $app['sluggable']->make($model);
    });
}
```

Since I switched to Confide for authentication the slugs are not getting generated.

My user model is simply `class User extends ConfideUser`. Switching to class `User extends Ardent` or `User extends Eloquent` the event `eloquent.saving` is getting triggered fine.

I'm not shure if this is a bug or I'm missing something.

My Model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;

class User extends ConfideUser
{

    public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';


    /**
     * Soft delete
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $softDelete = true;

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = array(
        'nickname',
        'password',
        'email',
        'deleted_at',
        'disabled',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'birthday',
        // needed by ardent
        'email_confirmation',
        'password_confirmation'
    );

    public static $rules = array(
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|confirmed|unique:users',
        'email_confirmation' => 'required',
        'nickname' => 'required|min:2|unique:users',
        'birthday' => 'date:d.m.Y|before:now',
        'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required'
    );

    public $imageSizes = array(
        array(64, 64),
        array(250, 250)
    );

    public static $sluggable = array(
        'build_from' => 'nickname',
        'save_to' => 'slug',
    );

    /**
     * Roles
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'Role',
            'role_user'
        )
            ->withTimestamps();;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like this one is a bug: https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/179

As a temporary workaround you can wrap the `beforeSave()` method in your Model without returning anything (!):

```
public function beforeSave($forced = false)
{
    parent::beforeSave($forced);
}
```